# Send multiple data to PHP using ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using a script to retrieve data from my database.

With `data: {'single_cal4' : jQuery('#single_cal4').val()},` The script sends the value to a php script and the php script sends a response back.

But now I want to send multiple values to the PHP script. `single_cal4` is already been sent I also want to send `single_cal5` in the same script.

Does someone know how I can send multiple data to the PHP file?

Here is my full script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> 
function getBel(value) {
    console.log("getBel before ajax", jQuery('#single_cal4').val());
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: './getbel/get1.php', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {'single_cal4' : jQuery('#single_cal4').val()},
        success: function(response){ 
            console.log("getBel after ajax", jQuery('#single_cal4').val());
            jQuery('#1al').val(response);
        }, 
        error: function (request, status, error) { 
            alert(request.responseText); 
        }, 
    });                 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Um... `{'single_cal4' : jQuery('#single_cal4').val(), 'single_cal5' : jQuery('#single_cal5').val() }` ?

Comment: when you say multiple data, you mean like number of fields or a object? e.g. "single_cal4" will receive person information like name, address, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the values to the data object:

```js
<script> 
function getBel(value) {
    console.log("getBel before ajax", jQuery('#single_cal4').val());
    jQuery.ajax({ 
        url: './getbel/get1.php', 
        method: 'POST', 
        data: {
                 'single_cal4' : jQuery('#single_cal4').val(),
                 'single_cal5' : jQuery('#single_cal5').val(),
                 'standardValue' : "STANDARD VALUE OPTIONAL" 
              },
        success: function(response){ 
            console.log("getBel after ajax", jQuery('#single_cal4').val());
            jQuery('#1al').val(response);
        }, 
        error: function (request, status, error) { 
            alert(request.responseText); 
        }, 
    });                 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: @John If there's an error, check your server log to see the reason.